# How to run a compiled java project

Tags: java, maven, libraries

I am new to maven. In order to compile my project I hit mvn compile. However I can't figure out how I can run my project from inside the maven. For instance when I hit

mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="main.java.org.dbalancer.StartProgram"

maven complaints:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sanityinc/jargs/CmdLineParser$OptionException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sanityinc.jargs.CmdLineParser$OptionException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 6 more
```

which means that jargs library is not included in classpath. However in my project there aren't any libraries included under target folder which means any library I use I should download it on my own and included in classpath (or use .m2/ folder).
For instance, when I am under target/classes folder, and I have downloaded all the necessary libraries this command works:
    java -cp .:../../lib/jargs-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:../../../dom4j-2.0.0-ALPHA-2.jar:../../../log4j-1.2.17.jar main.java.org.dbalancer.StartProgram

However isn't that a little verbose? How can I run that from inside maven? Can I run it using java command but not downloading on my own the necessary libraries ?

**Update**: Ok the problem was a library that I included in that way:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jargs_local</groupId>
  <artifactId>jargs</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/jargs-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Now jargs where moved to official maven repo. **However does anyone know how can I speed up mvn exec?** It's a bit slow if you just want to check something..

Comment: You need to download the jar files for resolving dependencies. I would recommend using Eclipse and maven plugin in it. So you don't have to import libraries every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maven-exec plugin should set up the classpath for you. Are you perhaps missing jargs as dependency in your `pom.xml` (can we see that as well as the complete mvn dump?)

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to build a self-sufficent runnable jar is to build a jar-with-dependencies with the maven assembly plugin.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html

Answer (score 1):

you should dependency them int the pom.xml
for example：

```
  <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0</version>
     </dependency>
```

or

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
                  <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                  <compilerArguments>
                   <extdirs>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib</extdirs>
                 </compilerArguments>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/swingx-0.9.3.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```